# Resize and cache images on the fly vs saving different sizes on server

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, gdlib

I've been reading about resizing images on the fly using some php scripts with URL rewriting (/img/500x500/image-name.jpg), but a lot of people say it's a bad practice as it's a RAM and CPU consuming (1Mb image uses about 3Mb of RAM). So I thought I would just generate these images once and then save them in a cache folder, that way I can keep the original img and also the resized ones in this folder.

I'm currently saving 3 different sizes in the server when the image is being uploaded (100x100, 200x200, 500x500). Few time ago I used to display some images in 500x500, but now I have changed a little bit the design to display these images in only 300x300, So I'm now stuck with large images which could slow a little bit the page load!

So what I'm thinking to do is to save the original image (1500x1500), and when it's being viewed for the first time, i'll generate the appropriate thumbnails and save them in a folder on the server. That way, if I ever change the design again, I can simply delete the image cache folder to create the new thumbnails with the new sizes...

I still don't have any codes as the website is still being developed and I'm just trying to anticipate these facts. it's an ecommerce website

Do you think this is a wise way to deal with images??

I'm using php7, nginx, laravel 5 and also a CDN service (maxCDN)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally, yes, you want to save a copy of the generated image somewhere (local cache, CDN, S3 bucket, etc) so you don't have to go through the computationally-heavy task of creating a new image each time you want to display it. How you implement the specifics is up to you. This question is too general to be answerable in its current format. If you have specific questions about implementation (with examples of code you've tried), then post it here and we can help with more detailed responses.

Comment: @ArmanH I'm reading again your message one one thing arises my curiosity: You said "save a copy of the generated images in CDN", is it possible to save images only in CDN and not in our server??

Comment: Sure, check out [Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/), which abstracts interaction with cloud/CDN providers (push, pull, delete, replace files, etc) and lets you treat them as if they were local disks. Ideally, though, you'd want to generate the image on the local server, push it to the cloud, verify the transfer completed successfully, then delete your local copy.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, your question is too broad to be answerable. You are asking for general advice and/or strategy, not help with specific code logic or errors. So yes, the hold is normal.

Comment: Well, I've edited my post trying to give as much details as I can, but I don't see what else I can say :)

Comment: You added details, but it didn't change the nature of your question. Asking "is something a good idea" is considered too broad/opinion based on this site. If you want an example, `@Serge` gave you sample code. And you should really get into the habit of accepting the answers you find helpful. Most of your questions have answers, but only a few accepts.

Comment: I didn't mark the answer of Serge cause the purpose of my post wasn't to get code samples, but rather to have your professional opinion on doing the resizing on the fly as I didn't find a very pertinent answer in the net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this for thumbnails... pretty easy with Intervention image library... I mean, simple... http://image.intervention.io/

```
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// now you are able to resize the instance
$img->resize(320, 240);

// finally we save the image as a new file
$img->save('public/bar.jpg');
```

That's it... and yes, resizing on the fly is a bad idea...

Comment: thanks for the link! You say resizing on the fly is a bad idea, but is it also bad if you do it only ONCE per image and then you save them in a folder??

Comment: I guess that would be even better... as you only resize images you would be using... an image that is never accessed again would never get resized that way. It's just not a good idea to do cpu intensive operations while you are processing a request, it just doesn't scale ...

Comment: what you mean with CPU intensive operations?

Comment: Image processing is generally expensive in both memory and cpu cycles. It will keep your CPU busy for a long time. Everything being relative, imagine you are transforming images at every request, this adds the cpu processing time to every request, thus potentially slowing down the entire server as CPU cores are a limited resource. Imagine 1000 requests, all scaling images at the same time! This would be desastrous on both memory and cpu usage. Could potentially grind your server to a halt... Best practice is to minimize the amount of processing done for each request so you can respond fast...

Comment: I see, let's say I'm migrating the website to a new server and don't transfer the cache folder that contains all the generated images, or simply just delete this folder to adapt images sizes to a new design layout. If the website has about 10k visitors/ day, do you think the server will suffer from generating these images for the first clients?

Comment: This all really depends on how these images are organized. Let's say you're generating 5 of the same images on the homepage. This request will be very slow for the first visitor, but very quickly for everyone after, because those images will be generated. Now, if you have users visiting their profiles which contain individual image galleries (for example, Flickr), then each users' images will have to be generated separately. Whether the server can handle this kind of a load depends on what kind of infrastructure you have, so it's hard to say if it will crash or not.